# geodesic on an ellipsoid

Tags: differential-geometry

Find all the geodesics which pass through the point $(a, 0, 0)$ on the ellipsoid $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{z^2}{c^2}=1$. What parametrization can i use to get the first fundamental form? and how to continue after calculating E,F and G?